# Arduino expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c, arduino

I was trying to seperate my old working code in modules but I got always this error.

```
"nfc_read.h:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token"
```

this is line 24:
`void read_card(boolean *success,uint8_t *uid,uint8_t *uidLength);`

not sure what is wrong in the code...

In my header nfc_read.h:

```
#ifndef _nfc_read_h_
  #define _nfc_read_h_

//Libarys
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.h>


void setup_adafruit(int mode);  
void read_card(boolean *success,uint8_t *uid,uint8_t *uidLength);//<--here is the error

#endif
```

Maybe here is the mistake somewhere:

```
#include "nfc_read.h"

#define IRQ   (2)  // IRQ = Interrupt request uint8 (input)
#define RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield uint8 (output)

void setup_adafruit(int mode)
{
  Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C nfc(IRQ, RESET); //Funktionspointer....Pins konfigurieren IRQ => input ,RESET => output

  Serial.println("Welcome this application will read your UID of your ISO14443A-Card"); //Willkommens Text

  nfc.begin(); 

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion(); 

  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find Arduino board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");  
}

void read_card(boolean *success,uint8_t *uid,uint8_t *uidLength)
{
  *success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength);
}
```

Comment: (Not the bug) ::`#define _nfc_read_h_` :: dont use identifiers that start with an underscore. They are reserved.

Comment: Can you clarify which line (#24 as per your indication) is causing the error?

Comment: @wildplasser even when I remove the defines nothing changes...

Comment: Best guess is that he forgot to `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: I agree with @wildplasser.  Either stdint.h has not been successfully included, or the 'boolean' type is not successfully defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help?

```
#ifndef _nfc_read_h_
  #define _nfc_read_h_

//Libarys
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.h>
```

Add the following lines:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef boolean
    #define boolean int
#endif
```

The above lines will ensure that the proper types are defined.

```
void setup_adafruit(int mode);  
void read_card(boolean *success,uint8_t *uid,uint8_t *uidLength);//<--here is the error

#endif
```